# Does Terraform supports role assignment?

Tags: terraform

Does Terraform support doing something like this in Azure CLI?

```
   az role assignment create --assignee ${var.assignee} --role Reader --scope /subscriptions/${var.subscription_id}/resourceGroups/${var.registry_name}/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/${var.registry_name}
```

Currently I'm doing something like this with Terraform

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
  command = "az login --service-principal -u ${var.client_id} -p ${var.client_secret} --tenant ${var.tenant_id}"
}

provisioner "local-exec" {
  command = "az role assignment create --assignee ${var.assignee} --role Reader --scope /subscriptions/${var.subscription_id}/resourceGroups/${var.registry_name}/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/${var.registry_name}"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It looks like the upstream issue for this support is https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/16.